# Don't want to delete object when shared_ptr get out of scope --Closed

Tags: c++

I have a situation that I have some code like this. We need to add child objects to a clean up list, which will delete these children later when the class get destroyed. But we wish to use set for internal safety reasons, and obviously the set has longer lifetime.

```
//This is will delete twice, if this is called later.
~classX(){
    cleanList.clear();
}

classX::addToCleanList(T* child){
    set<shared_ptr<T> > cleanList;

    shared_ptr<T> p = shared_ptr(child);

    //Set has a customized comparetor
    //If the set already has the object pointer, insert will fail 
    //and the shared_ptr will get out of the scope 
    cleanList.insert(p);
}
//When it gets out of scope, p will be destroyed.
```

This will cause issue, since the child objects are still needed.

Any solution to this? I don't see unique_ptr or shared_ptr and move semantic 
can avoid being deleted when they get out of the scope.

Comment: Why not just check to see if the set already contains the object before you create the `shared_ptr` for it?

Comment: First thing cleanList in addToCleanList function has the scope of the function when function return it destroyed. You can change the interface  addToCleanList as- addToCleanList(shared_ptr<T> child)

Comment: "the child objects are still needed" - okay, so think about why they're still needed and try to represent that as an object lifetime.  That's where your (another?) `shared_ptr` should go.

Comment: why you need `shared_ptr<T>`? Isn't just store all the raw pointer and delete them in destructor simpler?

Comment: @appleapple Actually, I vote the set of raw pointers, but my team has some concerns of the memory leak, so I wonder any smart_ptr can be used in this case. But if this is the wrong way, I will insist the right way to use raw pointers in set or vector.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, that could be a way. Maybe I can try that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys. I basically have an idea to deal with this.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't manage the object ownership only in your classX class. These objects probably need to be shared_ptrs in other code as well. These objects are passed to the addToCleanList function as a raw pointer from somewhere. Who owns those pointers? You should manage the lifetime of the objects in one central location if you can, and only use raw pointers in places where there is no ownership.

Comment: This is a base class, and the descendants owns the objects. Actually, I vote the set of raw pointers, but my team mates have some concerns of the memory leak so I wonder any smart_ptr can be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This code has a number of issues that make it really hard to understand what is the actual problem:

- `cleanList` has the scope of `addToCleanList` function. Judging by the names and by the fact that `cleanList` does literally nothing this way, I'd say the intention was to make it the `classX` member.
- the `set.insert(p)` statement - how does it even compile? Don't you mean `cleanList.insert(p)`?
- The whole idea of using `std::set` here is a bit weird. Seems like you're trying to reinvent the `shared_ptr` functionality on a grander scale, but then you're still using `shared_ptr` after that.
  Using a `vector` of `shared_ptr` would be just as fine, and no need for custom comparators.

All of those kinda indicate possible major design problems here, so further help is somewhat hindered by that; e.g. I have a strong suspiction you won't need `shared_ptr` at all after you carefully plan the lifetime of your objects.

Comment: The reason to transfer to shared_ptr is that the 'set' is wrapped by a wrapper invented by our company, which may have insert failures, and then the child object will not be destroy in the end. 1. Here I put the the code in the pseudocode way, and I simplify the scenario and remove some unrelated statements. 2.Thanks to point out cleanList.insert(p), and I edited it.3.Right. I know Set is wired there, but  our team votes for set to prevent pointer to pointing the same object to avoid double deleting.Using a vector of shared_ptr to cleanup may double kill obj, since shared_ptrs are independent?

Comment: I decide to roll it back and use raw pointers, instead of the shared_ptr. Thanks.

Comment: @Gongbaochicken having independent `shared_ptr`s pointing to the same object is a design error. To be honest I can hardly understand how it even came to be, this would require an actual effort on developer's site. But if you just copy `shared_ptr`s they will not be independent and will behave perfectly in a `vector`

Comment: Yes, the way to come to this pointer is complex. I admit this is a bad design. But luckily we know how to deal with this. Thank you~